# What causes the horizontal scrollbar to appear on Chrome in the following most trivial HTML?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

HTML:

```
<html>

  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
   font:13px/1.231 arial;
 }
 input {
   font:99% arial;
 }
 div {
   display: inline-block;
   overflow: auto;
 }
 input {
   width: 15em;
 }
```

The result on Chrome:

[image]

The jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/XBvWb/18/

Note that neither FF nor IE9 show this scrollbar.

Can anyone enlighten me, please, what is going on?

**EDIT**

Removed the input border, padding and margin - http://jsfiddle.net/XBvWb/41/

Comment: Its the `overflow:auto` on the div

Comment: Please, see my responses to the answers below.

Comment: if I set the div as block-inline, the scrollbar disappears

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue in my version of Chrome.  However, every browser is going to render `input` differently with their own padding, borders, etc.  What you're seeing is how Chrome is handling the relationship between the `input` and its container.  The container is big enough for the `input` but it's failing to make it big enough to handle the padding & border.  In other words, you're simply seeing a rendering difference between browsers.

Comment: @cristi_b, there is no such thing as `block-inline`, so essentially what you did is the same as simply removing `inline-block` entirely.

Comment: mark, you'll have to explain the point of your edit.  As explained, I cannot see your issue in my version of Chrome.  If it were that simple, I would have posted my comment as an answer.  Chrome is calculating the size of it's parent differently than how it's calculating the size of the input... a rendering issue, a bug,  whatever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess is that Chrome has a problem with rounding.

If you use any value of px for the inputs width the scrollbar disappears.
Same when you change the inputs font-size to 100% (which equals exactly 13px in this example).

The current width of the input is 15 * 99% * 13px = 193.05px

I think the .05px let the scrollbar appear.

That also clarifies why the scrollbar disappears for widths of around 11em. It just rounds up in manner Chrome can handle better.

Comment: +1, good answer.  Every browser handles these things differently.  For Chrome, how the parent container's size is calculated is clearly not the same as how the element's size is calculated.

Comment: This is absolutely so. I changed 99% to 100% and it is OK now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the following line is causing the extra scroll bar:

```
overflow: auto;
```

you could also just leave it and add an explicit width to the div:

```
width: 100%;
```

or make the div a block level element

```
display:block
```

Basically you're never supposed to put a `block` level element inside an `inline-block` level element.

Comment: Why overflow auto is a problem? I do not see any element overflowing anything, in which case auto should not present any scrollbar.

Comment: it's just how chrome treats its `inline-block` level elements. If you used `display:block` it would be fine as well. By convention you're never supposed to put anything that is a `block` level element inside an `inline-block` element (in your case, a `textbox` inside of a `inline-block` div).

Comment: An `input` is not considered a block-level element, so should be nothing wrong with putting it inside an `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

overflow:auto forces a scrollbar if the content is clipped. Your width: 15em on the input is causing the content to be clipped thus forcing a scrollbar to appear.

Comment: Why does it force the content to be clipped? If 15em clips the content, then 14em surely not - right? Well wrong, change 15em to 14em and you will see the same effect.

Comment: I think the problem actually lies with display: inline-block, if you change this to display: inline, it should solve the problem.

Comment: Also it stops clipping at 11em.

Comment: So, the clip region size is 15em-11em=4em? Then why it is only a few pixels if judging by the scrollbar? BTW, I can change the font settings too and the problem disappears.

Comment: @mark, it's a issue with how Chrome is handling your particular situation.  All browsers are not created by the same people... each one will have it's little differences or bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue where a horizontal scroll box is appearing in Chrome but not Firefox.

If your site (like most sites) does not use horizontal scroll, you can fix this issue by simply hiding all overflow on the x axis like this:

```
body {
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Note: or you could set it on the `html` tag too. Not sure which is better.